# cakephp join does not return associated model data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have three models in a cakephp application: `ModelX`, `ModelY` and `ModelZ`. The table for ModelX has the fields parent_id, lft and rght. The associations between the models are as follows:

```
ModelX hasOne ModelY
ModelY belongsTo ModelX
ModelY hasMany ModelZ
ModelZ belongsTo ModelY
```

I have a query on ModelX with joins to ModelY and ModelZ like this:

```
$this->ModelX->find('all', array(
            'joins' => array(
                    array(
                            'table' => 'modelys',
                            'alias' => 'ModelY1',
                            'type' => 'left',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                    'ModelX.id = ModelY1.modelx_id',
                            )
                    ),
                    array(
                            'table' => 'modelzs',
                            'alias' => 'ModelZ1',
                            'type' => 'left',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                    'ModelY1.id = ModelZ1.modely_id'
                            )
                    )
            )

));
```

In the result of this query, I have the data for ModelX, ModelY but NOT ModelZ, I don't know why!!. Can anybody see what is wrong with this query please?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's nothing wrong with your query. Using model_id (convention over configuration) seems more practical, but if your setup need it, keep it then.

Just add this before your query.

```
$this->ModelX->recursive = 2;
```

On [CakePHP Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive), you need to set recursion to all linked models. Be careful, this might be more slow and/or return undesired data.